# canvas in inner class, android

Tags: android, canvas, inner-classes

Is it possible to have a class extending `SurfaceView` within the activity class as an inner class? Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<com.android.iiProject.Presentation.DrawCanvas
android:id="@+id/SurfaceView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Where the `Presentation` is the activity class, and the `DrawCanvas` is the class extending the `SurfaceView`, and a `DrawCanvas` object is called from within the `Presentation` activity.

I want it this way because I want to have access to methods and variables available from within the `Presentation` activity, and I don't want to declare them as static to reach them from the other class, since that causes me a lot of additional problems...!
This way it's giving me `classNotFoundException` at the XML file

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's possible, you just have to adress you inner class in a different way from XML, like this:

```
<view
  class="com.yourpackage.YourOuterClass$YourInnerClass" 
  ...
  />
```

Quote:

> The custom component is created as a generic view in the XML, and the
>   class is specified using the full package. **Note also that the inner
>   class we defined is referenced using the NoteEditor$MyEditText
>   notation which is a standard way to refer to inner classes in the Java
>   programming language.** If your custom View component is not defined as
>   an inner class, then you can, alternatively, declare the View
>   component with the XML element name, and exclude the class attribute.

*See [modifying an existing view type](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#modifying), point 4.*

Comment: Thank you a lot for the reply, it worked!
but now i'm getting a classCastException when I refer to the DrawCanvas (the inner class), since it's declared as the generic object "View" in the XML, shouldn't be able to be cast to a DrawCanvas?!
the problematic sentence :

    DrawCanvas mycanvas = (DrawCanvas)     findViewById(R.id.SurfaceView);